# Save static browser image to local folder

Tags: google-maps

I am using the Google Static Maps API, to construct a URL with the necessary parameters, which then displays in the browser.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

How can I automatically save the static map image which is displayed in the browser?

Currently, I have to right-click over image and 'Save image as...', in order to get the image into the required folder.  I would like to automate this last step.

Here is a sample URL:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap&scale=1&markers=color:red|label:S|610+Beech+St+W,Whitby&markers=color:blue|label:1|43.8764737,-78.945162&markers=color:blue|label:2|43.8975446,-78.9429329&markers=color:blue|label:3|43.8828564,-78.9294267&markers=color:blue|label:4|43.8828564,-78.9294267&markers=color:blue|label:5|43.903265,-78.956063&markers=color:blue|label:6|43.8780157,-78.9590955&markers=color:blue|label:7|43.886099,-78.952875&key=AIzaSyC5FiaYcLsRwaSxOhcOzqejdN_xzCwVIJ8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use case might be in contradiction with Google Maps API Terms of Service. Section 10.5 (d) states:

> **No caching or storage.** You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:
>
> is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
>
> is secure;
>
> does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
>
> does not modify attribution in any way.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to where you can find the relevant [terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms) now:

3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.

(a)  No Scraping. Customer will not export, extract, or otherwise scrape Google Maps Content for use outside the Services. For example, Customer will not: (i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost Google Maps Content outside the services; (ii) bulk download Google Maps tiles, Street View images, geocodes, directions, distance matrix results, roads information, places information, elevation values, and time zone details; (iii) copy and save business names, addresses, or user reviews; or (iv) use Google Maps Content with text-to-speech services.

(b) No Caching. Customer will not cache Google Maps Content except as expressly permitted under the Maps Service Specific Terms.